# Boostrap 5, How can I add multiple elements in a column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have this Bootstrap 5 code that [shows some images like in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fsff.png) in a grid, the images are affected by a few CSS code.

```
#projects img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```
<section id="projects">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-3 border-bottom border-3">Mis Proyectos</h4>
                <div class="row g-4">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img
                        src="./images/cardcomponent.png" 
                        alt="card component"
                        class="rounded-3"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img
                        src="./images/yardsale.png" 
                        alt="yard sale"
                        class="rounded-3"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img
                        src="./images/qrcard.png" 
                        alt="web developer"
                        class="qr card"
                        >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <img
                        src="./images/cardcomponent.png" 
                        alt="web developer"
                        class="rounded-3"
                        >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I want to add a title `<h6></h6>` to each image.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h6>Title</h6>
    <img
    src="./images/cardcomponent.png" 
    alt="card component"
    class="rounded-3"
    >
</div>
```

But for some reason, the title isn't included or recognized in the column, showing something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDRlT.jpg), while [this is similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2ijw.jpg) to what i want to do.

Comment: Just asking why are you not using card component? Add `card` class to div and `card-title` class to h6 and enclose img inside another div with class `card-body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Emiliano Acevedo, Thanks to draw attention to the bug of bootstrap, I am sure the team must get those alignment issue fixed for row column.

Here's quick fix for the issue. `<div class="row g-4 align-items-end">` You can fix the issue with adding item alignment in the row element.

I hope this helps.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/dakshank/pen/BarMrRW)

Comment: Thanks! Hoping the bug gets fix soon.

Answer (score 0):

Div with `text-center` class makes all the text align at the center inside of it. But since you just want your `<h4>` tag align at the center only, just remove the `text-center` class from that div and add it to the `<h4>` tag. Once you do that, your `<h6>` tag inside of your column will work as you intended. Like:

```css
#projects img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="projects">
    <div class="container">
        <h4 class="text-center fw-bold mb-3 border-bottom border-3">Mis Proyectos</h4>
        <div class="row g-4">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h6>Title 1</h6>
                <img src="./images/cardcomponent.png" alt="card component" class="rounded-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h6>Title 2</h6>
                <img src="./images/yardsale.png" alt="yard sale" class="rounded-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h6>Title 3</h6>
                <img src="./images/qrcard.png" alt="web developer" class="qr card">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h6>Title 4</h6>
                <img src="./images/cardcomponent.png"  alt="web developer" class="rounded-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```